# HTML Table parsing using DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I Have a HTML Table

**My Parsing Code is**

```
$src = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$src->formatOutput = true;
$src->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$src->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($src);
$data=$xpath->query('//td[ contains (@class, "bodytext1") ]');
foreach($data as $datas)
{
echo $datas->nodeValue."<br />";
}
$values=$xpath->query('//tr[ contains (@bgcolor, "f3fafe") ]');
foreach($values as $value)
{
echo $value->nodeValue."<br />";
}
$values1=$xpath->query('//tr[ contains (@bgcolor, "def0fa") ]');
foreach($values1 as $value1)
{
echo $value1->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

to be printed, and I want them to be repeated along with other lines as shown above in output i need. 
and I want this whole thing in a array so that i can insert it in the database

Can anyone please guide me or give me any hint so that I can do this

Comment: Where do you load the HTML?

Comment: my html is in $result

Comment: For the first two searches you need to extract the nodeValues, extract from them the data you need, and  store it in variables. Then, on the third search, print each row, along with the data you extracted in the first two searches. It's difficult to be precise without the HTML to look at, and I can't access your Gist - post it here..

Comment: @MikeW My HTML is here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5592ff3ee08224f8f4ab & I am assigning it to $result here

Comment: @MikeW Question Edited sir, please have a look and please help me sir

Comment: Better. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
$src = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$src->formatOutput = true;
$src->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$src->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($src);

// get header data
$data=$xpath->query('//table[1]//td');

$htno = trim(explode(":",$data->item(0)->nodeValue)[1]);
$name = trim(explode(":",$data->item(1)->nodeValue)[1]);
$fatherName=trim(explode(":",$data->item(2)->nodeValue)[1]);

// rows from 2nd table 
$values1=$xpath->query('//table[2]//tr');
$header = true;  // flag to track whether we've read the header row.
foreach($values1 as $value1)
{
if (!$header) {
  $rowdata = str_replace("\r\n"," ",$value1->nodeValue);
  echo $htno," ",$name," ",$fatherName," ",$rowdata,"\n";
}
$header = false;
}
```

Note:

- The $header flag is a quick fix. A better Xpath query might eliminate the need for it.
- the `str_replace` near the bottom is ugly but expedient. You might want to play with the `xpath` query to see if you can improve it.
- Output is not formatted for HTML - lines are delimited by `\n`
- I got a warning on one line where it contained `&`, so I changed it to `AND`. You might have to preprocess your tables to eliminate those somehow.

Comment: getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' for $htno = trim(explode(":",$data->item(0)->nodeValue)[1]); this line sir

Comment: Which version of PHP? This works with PHP5.4 Try breaking the expression down to this:`$temp = explode(":",$data->item(0)->nodeValue); $htno = trim($temp[1]);`. You may need to do this for other lines too.

Comment: while printing with echo it is printing all the 8 rows but while inserting it in to the database table only first row is inserted

Comment: Then you have a problem with the code you've written to update the database. Ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

you could use third party's dll,such as "Html Agility Pack". a tool which is professional to convert html into xml.